# There is a plugin for reactjs called mongoose,can you help me with an alternative for that in spring boot?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, mongoose

There is a plugin for reactjs called mongoose,can you help me with an alternative for that in spring boot?,...

There is a plugin for reactjs called mongoose,can you help me with an alternative for that in spring boot?,.....

Comment: Mongoose is a NodeJS ODM - not a React Plugin. An ORM for Spring Boot would be something like Hibernate or Java Persistence API

Comment: In Mongodb

In Studio 3t In a collection having the records with a DBRef value, try to find out a way to query the field on the "name" parameter, instead of the ID.

In case, there is no other way to query the records for the DBRef except the ID, provide a valid/official documentation stating the reason behind it,

For reference, there is a library for NodeJs, called Mongoose, where the DBRef records can be queried using any other parameters, such as "name", instead of the ID. Try to find out if there is any other alternative for the same in SpringBoot.

Comment: Any idea about this?